# SeekBar Thumb se tapa con el background del seekbar

Tags: java, android

Actualmente tengo un SeekBar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mismo al colocarlo con progreso 0 se tapa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi seek

```
<SeekBar

    android:background="@drawable/btn_swipe"
    android:id="@+id/SeekBarContinuar"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="4"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbak"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
    />
```

Y este mi background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
</stroke>
```

Intente setearle el progreso a mano si baj de 0 pero genera un efecto feo de ver, alguna forma de que no pueda bajar de 4 o como fixear dicho problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso puedes agregar un padding, puedes aplicarlo solo en el lado izquiedo de la vista:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
```

ejemplo:

```
<SeekBar
    android:background="@drawable/btn_swipe"
    android:id="@+id/SeekBarContinuar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="4"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbak"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"/>
```